# Search and filter an RSS and send results via email to various recipients

Tags: email, rss

I wanted to know if there is a tool that goes through an RSS feed, filters out what you want(set by user previously) and then whatever results it gives out, sends an email to various recipients.

For example: 
Firefox version X has been released, send this to email@email.com
iOS 7.2 Developer has been released, send this to email@email.com

And so on...

Its something like http://www.albumreminder.com/ but only for software. Just so that I can keep up with the latest updates of specific software.

I have tried Mac/Windows Informer but that only scans the applications you have installed and checks for updates, doesn't do much more...

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with [If This Then That](http://ifttt.com) - connect an email account, and create recipes that will take items from an RSS feed and send an email.

IFTTT has the limitation of only being able to handle one feed at a time, but it would work.